# New connection doesn't show up in list of networks

Tags: 11.10, gnome, network-manager, lan

I added a new profile for wired connection in Ubuntu's network manager|Edit Connections|Wired, but the new connection doesn't show up in the list of networks when I click on the network icon in system tray.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

How did you set up the new wired connection? It should be automatically recognised when you plug an ethernet cable in.

Generally the Network Manager works well, you may want to read the [Community Documentation for Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager0.7) and follow the steps there to create the new wired network.

Comment: Network Connections|Wired|add ...

Comment: I should have clarified - what settings did you put in for the MAC address and IP4 connection type? Could you also type `ip link show` in a terminal a add the output to your question